# How can I easily verify if a core or module update has not broken anything?

Tags: updating, testing

When I update drupal core or even a couple of modules, I'm always afraid if something breaks. What easy way is there to test a site if anything has broken? Its not feasible for me to test a site that has over 1000 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Drupal core updates should not break Drupal core. If you upgrade `stable` community modules to a newer `stable` release -- again you should not encounter regression error problems.

That being said and long as your not the edge with alot of modules it shouldnt be such a huge worry -- but I similar worries. Backup, Backup, Backup always.

I doubt you have 1000s of *unique* pages. There are tools like [Selinium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), or [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or Java's [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) that let you script interactions with a webpage for known results. You could script your set of possible necessary functionalities on a handful of generic pages.

There's no way around testing if you really have to test and assure error-free site usage.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), which has nothing to do with Drupal but is open source.  I use the Selenium IDE Firefox extension on my machine locally, but [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) also offers paid services (I'm not a customer but I've heard good things).

Basically, with these tools, you define a series of tasks step-by-step.  Then, when you update core/modules, you run the tests and make sure they return the correct results (you define what the correct results are).

This takes significant time to set up.  When I was first starting out, it took me about three days to get a decent set of tests.  However, now I can quickly check for all the past known problems whenever I update my site, so I think the investment was worth it.